# Mlflow UI is taking forever to install and still not done

Tags: google-colaboratory, dashboard, mlflow

I am running my code on google colab to bring mlflow dashboard and whenever I ran !mlflow ui and it is taking forever to execute. The last text on my screen is the Booting worker with pid. This is my first time working with mlflow can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried to identify and then fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mlflow ui` to see logs, it doesn't install anything. In fact, it hosts a server using `gunicorn`. In order to connect to the tracking server created by Colab, reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615818/setting-up-mlflow-on-google-colab) could be useful. (Also [this doc](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#tracking-ui))

I recommend you to run `mlflow ui` command on your local host and then go to the listening address to see what happens. (Things tracked on the colab don't show here!)

Answer (score 0):

aimlflow might be helpful. It helps to run a beautiful UI on top of mlflow logs
the code: https://github.com/aimhubio/aimlflow

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please offer some insight into why this library might solve the poster's issue? Generally a link only answer without an example or explanation isn't acceptable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer